# External domain JavaScript referrer? how it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, referrer

so I have a question and I can't find an answer.

So I have a domain dario1.com which has a button that redirects to dario2.com

dario2.com has an JS code to tell the referrer and if te referrer is dario1 it will run a JS. And that works perfectly.

```
var ref1= document.referrer;
var search = "dario1";
if (ref1.indexOf(search) > -1)
    do_something();
else 
    void(0);
```

My question is:
If dario2.com has this code(in head tags) in an external JS on another domain like asdf.com(which i dont own).Can the asdf.com site tell my referrer? Or it will show dario2.com?

```
type="text/javascript" src="http://asdf.com/referrer.js"
```

I dont know how to test this(don't own more domains, also jsfiddle is kinda embeed so I don't know if it's good.), and also I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript runs on the local machine only. So anything you put in the `src=` attribute is basically telling your client to request the code from a particular location and run it locally. It *does not matter* where the code comes from, it will always be run the same!

The only way to access where the code came from (see what is inside the `src` attribute), is to look at the dom itself.

So to recap, the code you have pasted in your question will always run exactly the same, no matter where is was requested from.